# requests.Session POST not allowing login

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am attempting to scrape some data from an internal GUI for a modem in the field. Here is the code I am using:

```
## import the requests python library
import requests


## defines the login URL and the Post URL
post_loginURL = 'http://100.255.255.255/cgi-bin/login.cgi'

## defines the request URL to scrape from
requestURL = 'http://100.255.255.255/cgi-bin/stat_eth0.cgi'

## define the login data paramaters
payload = {
    'NAME': 'username',
    'PWD': 'password',
    'CMD': '1' ## hidden value being passed in the post request
}

## define the content type as text/html
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }

## creates the session object
with requests.Session() as session:

    ## sends the post request, headers and login data to the server
    post = session.post(post_loginURL, data=payload, headers=headers)
    r = session.get(requestURL)
    print(r.text)
```

Here is the HTML Error message I receive in the IDLE console:

```
<em><u><p align="right">ERROR: You must log in</u></em>
```

Here are the details from the Chrome Dev Tools:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OekRm.jpg)

I am unsure if I am just missing a crucial step, or if this is an issue with syntax, etc. Any constructive advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You used the response headers for your request, but this is wrong. You have to use the request headers and it should work.

Comment: I changed the headers, and I am getting the exact same error. Here is the pastebin for the most recent version: https://pastebin.com/YKSCbZx6

Comment: Posting the payload after each Get request did the trick.
I was actually able to omit the headers all together.


    with requests.Session() as session:

        ## sends the post request, headers and login data to the server
        g = session.get(post_loginURL)
        post = session.post(post_loginURL, data=payload)
    
        r = session.get(requestURL)
        post = session.post(requestURL, data=payload)